# Expressing a function in terms of other functions

Tags: fourier-series

I would like to know if it is possible to express a smooth function, $f(x)$, in terms of the sum of other functions of the form
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{A_i}{x+c_i},$$
over some finite domain. Where $A_i$ and $c_i$ are arbitrary constants which can be complex. I am only interested in real $x$ and so setting $c_i$ to an imaginary number removes the singularity. I know it is possible to express $f(x)$ in a Fourier series. I am looking for something similar to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any [meromorphic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function) $f(z)$ with poles at $z=c_i$ can be presented as
$$
f(z)=\sum_{ij}\frac{A_{ij}}{(z-c_i)^j}.
$$

This is the essence of the [Mittag-Leffler theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Mittag-Leffler_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for your help. To help me understand would you mind giving an example. What would the expansion for $\cos(x)$ look like? How do you calculate the series for a given $f(x)$?

Comment: @Peanutlex Cosine is holomorphic function. It means it has no poles. Therefore there is no expansion involving non-constant denominator. But maybe the Weierstrass factorization form will suit your purposes: $$\cos(\pi x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left[1-\left(\frac{2x}{2n-1}\right)^2\right].$$

Comment: Thank you. It seems $$\cos(\pi x)\approx\frac{\sinh(\pi)}{\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{1+\left(x-n\right)^{2}}.$$ I wonder if we can modify this to get a better approximation.

Comment: @Peanutlex This is the essence of my answer to your other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3585771). The question you put now is interesting but probably requires more precise definition of the approximation quality and of the allowed set of approximating functions.